# Auto_click_Script_with_ID_changing using(document.getElementById)

Tags: jquery, click, tampermonkey, auto

Hi I am trying to run an auto click function by

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("XXXXXXXXX").click();}, 1000);
```

But my ID changes with random numbers and first part is same

> Task_23587534 Task_93783638 Task_83937637

and want to run this function on each page. So, how do I do it if my last 8 digits always change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set an `onClick` event that would enable you to have the same function page to page ...  And instead of setting the id's to `Task_1010101010`, Pass the id into the function Like so:

```
<div id="whatever" onClick="MyFunction('10101010');">
```

And then have a JavaScript function that deals with the unique identifier

```
function MyFunction(id){
    // Do Stuff with the variable id which will be set to 10101010 in this case....
    alert(id);
}
```

---

If you wanted a **purely** `jQuery` way of handling this --  You could use a `data` attribute IE

```
<div class="Task" data_id="10101010'">
```

Then the jQuery could look like:

```
$(".Task").on('click', function() {
   alert($(this).attr("#data-id"));
});
```

Of course these are just examples of getting the id's into the functions .. BUT .. Setting timouts etc etc should be a piece of cake at that point.